# Taxes when year split between Switzerland and Germany

Tags: taxes, germany, switzerland

Last year I worked in Switzerland (L permit) from January until the end of July, and then worked in Germany for the remainder of the year. I am now resident in Germany and an EU Blue Card holder. I was taxed at source in both countries. My combined income in both countries is about 80k euros. I don't have any deductions to speak of.

It would seem that since I spent over half of the year in Switzerland, that country was my tax residence in 2016. However, when I inquired at the tax office in Basel before leaving, I was told I no longer had any obligations to them.

On the other hand, my Internet research leads me to believe that the German authorities will want to know about my earnings for the entire year and that although my Swiss earnings will not be taxed again, they could boost my tax rate in Germany.

I am aware that this is a somewhat complicated situation and that I should probably get a tax adviser. However, I'd like to have some idea of what to expect.

I will be filing a tax return in Germany, but do I need to file in Switzerland as well and does anybody owe anybody money here?